# How to expand two properties from a single select-object and pass it onto Test-Path?

Tags: powershell

I am having issues finding a way to expand two properties from select-object that I need to pass into Test-Path. The issue is if I do not expand the property and pass into Test-Path I will get @{} in the error - I think powershell treats it as an object?

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve this?

I have tried few things like below but to no avail...

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Database -Query $myquery | 
Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*JD*"} | Select @{Expression={$_.Name, $_.FileExtension -join "."}} | FT -HideTableHeaders
```

Ideally my query should return:

FileName.extension

that I can then pass onto Test-Path without powershell treating it as an object, but a string if I am not mistaken?

Edit 1: Not sure if it helps but thought I'd add it here just for more clarity hopefully.

My SQL table has data like this:

```
Column A | Column B
FileName | FileExtension
```

Edit 2: Including foreach loop for clarification and pipeline output

```
$FilePath = "\\Server1\Folder1\Folder2\"
foreach ($path in $myquery) {


$path2 = $FilePath + $path


# check FileExtensions if exist or not 

    if (!(Test-Path $path2)) 
    {
    Write-host " $path  | Does not exist"
    }
    
}
```

Pipeline output looks like this:

```
\\Server1\Folder1\Folder2\@{LiteralPath=FileName.ExtensionName}
# This is getting treated as does not exist because I have "@{LiteralPath=}" left in there, if I can remove it I should be golden
```

Comment: Can you show us output from `Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Database -Query $myquery |Get-Member`?

Comment: Name              Property              string Name {get;set;} ,  and FileExtension          Property              string FileExtension {get;set;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you want to combine filenames from two columns in the resulting query and next test if that file exists or not.

In that case try

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Database -Query $myquery | 
    Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*JD*"} | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # it is unclear what the column names really are..
        # your example shows 'Column A' and 'Column A', but your code uses 'Name' or 'FileName'
        # and 'FileExtension', so you have to decide which is which..
        $file = '{0}.{1}' -f $_.'Column A', $_.'Column B'.TrimStart(".")
        # hopefully your query results in a complete path and filename, if not,
        # provide the path to the file here:
        # $file = Join-Path -Path $FolderPathWhereTheFileShouldBeFound -ChildPath $file

        # now you can test if the file exists
        if (Test-Path -Path $file -PathType Leaf) {
            # do something here
            Write-Host "File '$file' exists" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        else {
            # bummer.. file not found
            Write-Host "File '$file' does NOT exist" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
```

Please read the inline comments because too much is still unclear to me..

Comment: That did it, thanks so much! One more thing if you don't mind, can you tell me what '{0}.{1}' do?

Comment: @JohnDoe `'{0}.{1}'` is a template string into which the placeholders `{0}` and `{1}` are replaced by the values after the `-f`. The [-f Format Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f) has lots of options to make combining strings a breaze. Have a look there!